# How to save all records into an array from the SQL SERVER database table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, sql-server-2014-express

I have a table in my database. I want to save all SQL SERVER Database Table records into the array.I searched everywhere all I am getting is to copying data from dataTable to array. Is that possible save all records into the array from the database table? If yes please help me. I would like to get the code in C#.

**Edited:**
I want to process all the rows in the DataTable but going row by row through Datatable is consuming more time. So I am looking for better performance with other features like arrays or structures may be.

Comment: SqlDataReader + Instantiate class by passing in field values, or using reflection.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution like EntityFramework or NHibernate?

Comment: @Habeeb In ADO.NET

Comment: @john Can you explain me with a code or link. It will be more helpful.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov Sorry to say this. I have seen the link which you shared but I am not able get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying but seems pretty expensive and probably not a good idea , we can probably find another approach to deal with your problem and take this one out completely.

However for your question , the answer goes something like this:

```
    public static void Main(string args[])
    {

        List<object> objectList = new List<object>();
        var commandText = "Select name  from sys.tables";

        SqlConnection sqlConn = null;//Initialize
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlConn);

        var sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            commandText = $"Select * from {sqlReader["name"]}";
            command = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlConn);

            var subReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (subReader.Read())
            {
                //Loop through and add to list
                objectList.Add();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I am not understanding this part in your code `commandText = $"Select * from {sqlreader["name"]}";` can you explain me

Comment: @DilipKumar, thats a dynamic string which will create a select command for all the tables in database. It's called Interpolated String.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use EF and load your data like this:

`var data = context.YourTable.ToList();`

[learn about EF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx)

but be aware that if you have a big table it may slow down your application and then you have to do some workarounds like paging. usually you may want to pass some criteria in [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method

also you can run a raw SQL query with EF:

`context.Database.SqlQuery<YourMappingClass>("SELECT * FROM YourTable")`

choosing how to connect to your databse is a matter of preference, I prefer EF you can use ADO.NET.

Using ADO:

```
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection()) 
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = "Server=[server_name];Database=[database_name];Trusted_Connection=true";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM YourTable", conn);
    }
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    var list = new List<YourMappingClass>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {

        var obj = new YourMappingClass();
        obj.Prop1=reader[0];
        obj.Prop2=reader[1];
        list.Add(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to use ADO.NET code. If possible can you help me with ADO.NET code?

Comment: @DilipKumar Simsons answer is ADO.NET

Comment: @bradbury9 Yes Just now I saw. Looking on that

Comment: See the amended answer